# How can I migrate from cloudformation to CDK without delete existing stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am building application with cloudformation template and now migrating to using CDK. But when I run cdk deploy command, it always complains about resources already exist even I use the same stack name. Is there a way run CDK without tear down any cloudformation stack?

I know there is import resources feature but my case is that the resources will belong to the stack managed by CDK. If I use `import`, that means the resources exist outside of the stack. How can I make it work automatically? The logic should be `import the resource if it exists, otherwise create it`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there will be some manual steps, however with a bit of work, most of these steps can be scripted. Here's roughly how I've done CF to CDK stack migrations in the past:

1. For all the resources you are wanting to migrate out of your old CF stack, set a [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) of Retain.
2. Do a CloudFormation stack update with these changes - this will 'detach' these resources from your stack when you delete the stack in the next step, so that they can be imported to your CDK stack.
3. Delete the CloudFormation stack. The resources in the stack should continue to exist.
4. Redefine the resources you are preparing to import in your CDK stack. Try to mirror your existing resources as closely as possible, this will help you consolidate any drifts after importing.
5. Import these detached resources to your CDK stack via a ChangeSet. You can do so either via the AWS Console directly, or via CLI (e.g. `aws cloudformation create-change-set --change-set-type IMPORT --resources-to-import ...`)
6. Run drift detection on your CDK CF stack. Fix any drifts. Ideally there would be none if you've modeled the resources correctly in CDK, however there may be small differences due to defaults set by CDK.

Comment: The second step `Do a CloudFormation stack update with these changes`. Shouldn't it be delete stacks?

Comment: You will want to update the stack first after setting the DeletionPolicy prior to deleting the stack itself, if you want to ensure the resources don’t get deleted together with the stack.

Comment: Ok, it sounds very complicated. If I keep the cloudforamtion stack name same, do I still need to go through this process?

Comment: Yes, keeping the same stack name between your old CF stack and new CDK generated CF stack could work too. I also have some experience with this - it's quite fiddly, as you will need to additionally match the resource IDs generated by CDK, e.g. via `myConstruct.node.defaultChild.overrideLogicalId('MyCurrentResourceLogicalId')` (normally CDK generates these for you). You'll probably get a better idea of what works for you by taking a sample resource or two and trying both solutions out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **import** existing resources to CDK. Further info about this as well as examples of this operation are provided in AWS docs for CDK:

- [Importing existing external resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/resources.html#resources_importing)

> You can turn the resource's ARN (or another identifying attribute, or group of attributes) into an AWS CDK object in the current stack by calling a **static factory method** on the resource's class.

Comment: I have to run it manually. Is there an automatic way to import existing resources?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao You can have a look at [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) which supports CDK. To which extend, I don't know.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao How did it go with the import? Have you tried?

Comment: I believe the import is not the solution I am looking for. I want the resource to be part of my stack. If I put the import command in CI, it will try to import the resource every time for a commit.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you couldn't.

The CDK is techncially a wrapper of CloudFormation to help user to use CloudFormation. It helps user to generate the raw CloudFormation template in JSON. (It is very bad experience to deal with raw CloudFormation template directly) For the feature request here, it is beyond the current support by CDK, but requires underlying support from the CloudFormation.